# GitHub mark color change HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, icons

On github.com, their icon (mark) next to the search bar changes to a blue color when you hover over it.
I downloaded the mark from their site, https://github.com/logos, and put it into a practice website I'm making with HTML and CSS.

How would I go about changing the color when someone hovers over it?

I have tried:

```
a:hover{
     color: green;
}
```

and

```
a:hover{
     background-color:green;
}
```

The first had no affect and the second changed only the background as expected.

How can I just change the mark's color?

Comment: Github use's .header-logo-invertocat:hover{color: #4183c4;} in their CSS so its probably another problem with your page, maybe the style is being overidden, can you link to your page?

Comment: I actually just started it so its still just some files on my computer. It hasn't been made into a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't using what you downloaded(the png)... They're using a custom font.

You can do the same thing with any "icon font."

Examples: http://fontawesome.io or http://www.css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/

Comment: Do you have any idea how or where I could get their custom font?

Comment: Open their page up with Safari or Chrome dev tools and then look under "Resources" for their custom font .woff. Right now the url is https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/octicons/octicons/octicons-192e5fbb927be7cdb8bdfa0ecb98d3574bd395e58f9d00e5dcdfce5bc9660ac0.woff but it's likely to change in the future...